# Disable dialog box that prompts for "Open/Save/Cancel" selection by user for SSRS 2012 report in PDF format from ASP.NET4.5 C# site

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I need to bypass/disable dialog box that prompts for "Open", "Save" or "Cancel" selection by user for SSRS report in PDF format from ASP.NET C# site.

I'm able to do the following:
Called and render the SSRS report in PDF from ASP.NET in C#
Save the PDF report in a specific drive *but* don't want the dialog box prompting for "Open", "Save" or "Cancel".

I want to disable or bypass this dialog box that needs user to select "Open", "Save" or "Cancel" (trying to avoid this extra click).  My code will read the saved PDF file and view in browser. I'm using ReportViewer to create report then render in PDF, so it's saved in C://PDFReports folder.

How can I force "Save or Cancel" or bypass this dialog box to not show?
Here is my code:

```
private void ShowReport()
{

    try
    {
        string urlReportServer = "http://devSSRS//ReportServer";
        ReportViewerSSRS.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote; // ProcessingMode will be Either Remote or Local
        ReportViewerSSRS.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(urlReportServer); //Set the ReportServer Url
        ReportViewerSSRS.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/FinanceReports/GrossProfitReport"; //Passing the Report Path                

        //Creating an ArrayList for combine the Parameters which will be passed into SSRS Report
        ArrayList reportParam = new ArrayList();
        reportParam = ReportDefaultPatam();

        ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[reportParam.Count];
        for (int k = 0; k < reportParam.Count; k++)
        {
            param[k] = (ReportParameter)reportParam[k];
        }

        //pass parmeters to report
        ReportViewerSSRS.ServerReport.SetParameters(param); //Set Report Parameters
        ReportViewerSSRS.ServerReport.Refresh();

       //output as PDF 
        byte[] returnValue = null;
        string format = "PDF";
        string deviceinfo = "";
        string mimeType = "";
        string encoding = "";
        string extension = "pdf";
        string[] streams = null;
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings = null;


        returnValue = ReportViewerSSRS.ServerReport.Render(format, deviceinfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=GrossProfitReport.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(returnValue);
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        string FileName = @"C/ReportFilesPDF/"
        FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(FileName);
        fs.Write(returnValue, 0, returnValue.Length);
        fs.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}


private ArrayList ReportDefaultPatam()
{
    string selYear = (string)(Session["Year"]);
    string selMonth = (string)(Session["Month"]);
    string selGroup1 = (string)(Session["Segment"]);


    ArrayList arrLstDefaultParam = new ArrayList();
    arrLstDefaultParam.Add(CreateReportParameter("Year", selYear));
    arrLstDefaultParam.Add(CreateReportParameter("Month", selMonth));
    arrLstDefaultParam.Add(CreateReportParameter("Segment", selSegment));
    return arrLstDefaultParam;
}

private ReportParameter CreateReportParameter(string paramName, string pramValue)
{
    ReportParameter aParam = new ReportParameter(paramName, pramValue);
    return aParam;
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!
Thank you so much,
chaydeee

Answer (score 0):

I used a helper function for this and would pass the SSRS url (with render tags) and the fileserver destination.

```
Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)
        Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
        Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
        Dim liCount As Integer = 1
        Try
            loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
            loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            'loRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
            loRequest.Timeout = 600000
            loRequest.Method = "GET"
            loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
            Do While liCount > 0
                liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
                loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
            Loop
            loFileStream.Flush()
            loFileStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```